# Убрать текущий дубль из <SELECT>

Tags: php, html

Как убрать дубль текущего статуса товара не сломав функционал?

При выборе статуса для записи в БД у меня в выпадающем меню появляется значения из БД + текущий статус товара.

Код:

```
<div class="form-group required">
  <label >выберите категорию</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select name="status_id" class="form-control">
      <option value=""><?php echo $product['name_product_status'];?></option> <!--выводит текущее значение из БД-->
        <?php foreach ($statuses as $status) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $status['id_product_status'];?>"><?php echo $status['name_product_status']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

В чем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего проверять при выводе элементов на соответствие с продуктом и давать ему атрибут selected

```
<div class="form-group required">
  <label >выберите категорию</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select name="status_id" class="form-control">
        <?php foreach ($statuses as $status) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $status['id_product_status'];?>" <?php echo ($status['id_product_status'] == $product['id_product_status']) ? 'selected' : '';?>><?php echo $status['name_product_status']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Если у Вас есть конечно в `$product` значение `id_product_status` тогда будет работать верно, если нет можете по имени сравнивать, но это не очень надежно.

Comment: значение `id_product_status ` есть, не отрабатывает

Comment: Что у вас выводит $product['id_product_status'] ? Это значение есть хоть в одном $status['id_product_status'] ?

Comment: судя по всему пока ничего, это параметр, который нужно выбрать, чтоб записать в БД

Comment: Ну как то же вы выводили $product['name_product_status'] значит в $product что-то есть, код рабочий это точно, какие то данные не передаете скорее всего

Comment: есть значения!
    (
    [id_product] => 100
    [name_product] => name
    [href] => http://mysite
    [name_image] => http://mysite/image/macbook_air.jpg
    [name_desc] => description
    [name_product_status] => в продаже
    [id_product_status] => 2
)

Comment: работает! благодарю за помощь!